# Finding max and min indices in lists in Python

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list that looks like:

```
trial_lst = [0.5, 3, 6, 40, 90, 130.8, 129, 111, 8, 9, 0.01, 9, 40, 90, 130.1, 112, 108, 90, 77, 68, 0.9, 8, 40, 90, 92, 130.4]
```

The list represents a series of experiments, each with a minimum and a maximum index. For example, in the list above, the minimum and maximum would be as follows:

```
Experiment 1:
Min: 0.5
Max: 130.8

Experiment 2:
Min: 0.01
Max: 130.1

Experiment 3:
Min: 0.9
Max: 103.4
```

I obtained the values for each experiment above because I know that each
experiment starts at around zero (such as 0.4, 0.001, 0.009, etc.) and ends at around 130 (130, 131.2, 130.009, etc.). You can imagine a nozzle turning on and off. When it turns on, the pressure rises and as it's turned off, the pressure dips. I am trying to calculate the minimum and maximum values for each experiment.

What I've tried so far is iterating through the list to first mark each index as max, but I can't seem to get that right.

Here is my code. Any suggestions on how I can change it?

```
for idx, item in enumerate(trial_lst):
    if idx > 0:
        prev = trial_lst[idx-1]
        curr = item
        if prev > curr:
            result.append((curr, "max"))
        else:
            result.append((curr, ""))
```

I am looking for a manual way to do this, no libraries.

Comment: `max((a,i) for (i,a) in enumerate(trial_lst))` and `min((a,i) for (i,a) in enumerate(trial_lst))` will give you the max/min values and their indices but I don't see how the experiments are related.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this only returns the min value and its index

Comment: The title of your question does not match what you are asking. Also, where are the denominations in your list for the different experiments???

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Do you want to split the trial list in certain way?

Comment: I am looking to return multiple max and min values for each experiment. Experiments start around 0 and end around 130, so I am trying to figure out a way to calculating max and min by comparing each element.

Comment: Please explain, precisely, how you obtained the values for experiments 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you want to split the trial list into three different lists with most similar distributions?

Comment: I could split them, but I am thinking more so along the lines of comparing each element. I'm curious if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the easiest way ( sort your list or array first ):

```
trial_lst = [0.5, 3, 6, 40, 90, 130.8, 129, 111, 8, 9, 0.01, 9, 40, 90, 130.1, 112, 108, 90, 77, 68, 0.9, 8, 40, 90, 92, 130.4]

trial_lst.sort(key=float)

for count, items in enumerate(trial_lst):

    counter = count + 1
    last_object = (counter, trial_lst[count], trial_lst[(len(trial_lst)-1) - count])

    print( last_object )
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It does not maintain the order of the maximum values. For instance, it prints out that max of the first period as 130.4 rather than 130.8

Comment: @Dunes : LOL ... its because of 0.01! i did not see that, no problem just change key=int to key=float!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the index of the minimum value using the following:

```
my_list.index(min(my_list))
```

Comment: thanks, but this only returns the minimum value. I am looking to return multiple max and min values for each experiment. Experiments start around 0 and end around 130, so I am trying to figure out a way to calculating max and min by comparing each element..but to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by 'multiple max and min values'?

Comment: I mean that the list is comprised of multiple experiments. Each with one min value and one max value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interactive demonstration which may help:

```
>>> trial_lst = [0.5, 3, 6, 40, 90, 130.8, 129, 111, 8, 9, 0.01, 9, 40, 90, 130.1, 112, 108, 90, 77, 68, 0.9, 8, 40, 90, 92, 130.4]
```

Use values below 1 to identify where one experiment ends and another begins

```
>>> indices = [x[0] for x in enumerate(map(lambda x:x<1, trial_lst)) if x[1]]
```

Break list into sublists at those values

```
>>> sublists = [trial_lst[i:j] for i,j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])[1:]]
```

Compute max/min for each sublist

```
>>> for i,l in enumerate(sublists):
...     print "Experiment", i+1
...     print "Min", min(l)
...     print "Max", max(l)
...     print
... 
Experiment 1
Min 0.5
Max 130.8

Experiment 2
Min 0.01
Max 130.1

Experiment 3
Min 0.9
Max 130.4
```

Comment: I didn't think of breaking it into sublists. this is really helpful, thanks!